# Computing the integral of $\int \frac{n^x}{n^{2x} + 8n^x + 12}dx$

Tags: calculus

This question has already been answered when I searched for it but I was already able to get to slightly farther than what was given in the question. I was able to simplify this to $$\int \left(\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n^x+6} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n^x+2}\right) dx,$$ using partial fractions, but I'm not sure how to go further from this. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you explicitly substitute $n^x=y$?

Comment: If it has already been answered, why was that answer not enough? What makes you think this integral has a closed form?

Comment: This problem is easier without the partial fractions step. Well, really just delaying it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just supposed it did since they said it's easy from here (probably implying that there's more simplification to it

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I substituted it to make it easier to create the partial fractions setting, then put the $n^x$ back into the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

With the subsitution

$$t:=n^x,$$ the integrand is a rational fraction.

$$\int\frac{n^x}{n^{2x}+8n^x+12}dt\propto\int\frac {dt}{t^2+8t+12}=\int\frac {dt}{(t+4)^2-4}.$$

The last one is easy.

Comment: I realize you didn’t write equality, but it seems important to remember the $\frac1{\log n}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: hint means "you have to fill the holes".

Comment: Also, you have two $dt$s in your middle integral.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I think I got it! :)

Comment: I know what hint means, but I don’t know what $\propto$ means, and I doubt OP does, either.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: means $\dfrac1{\log n}$ was dropped ;-)

Comment: Congratulations for the $200$ k !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: cheers ! Your turn now !

Answer (score 2):

$\int \frac{n^x}{n^{2x} + 8n^x + 12}dx$

$\implies \int \frac{n^x}{(n^x+4)^2-4}dx$

let,$n^x+4=t \implies (n^x \ln n) dx=dt$

$n^x dx =\frac{dt}{\ln n}$

$\implies \frac{1}{\ln n}\int \frac{dt}{ (t^2-4)}$  which can be easily calculated

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Would I then use partial fractions to compute the integral of $\frac{dt}{t^2-4}$? And once I find that, would I once again have to plug in $t=n^x+4$ and use the chain rule for the derivative?

Comment: @user890948 yes,you can use partial fractions but there is a direct formula for that https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/show-integral-dx-x-2-2-1-2a-ln-x-x-c-notequalto-0-show-integral-dx-x-2-2-1-tan6-1-x-c-q21611971

Comment: I see ok, thank you for the link and your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\int\frac{dx}{n^x + c} = \begin{bmatrix}t = n^x + c \\ dt = n^x\ln n dx \\ dx = \frac{1}{(t-c)\ln n}dt\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\ln n}\int\frac{dt}{t(t-c)} = \frac{1}{c\ln n} \int\left(\frac{1}{t-c} - \frac{1}{t}\right)dt = \frac{1}{c\ln n} \ln \left|\frac{t-c}{t}\right| +C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{n^x}{n^{2x} + 8n^x + 12}dx$$
$$n^x=t$$
$$n^x\ln(n)=\frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$dx=\frac{dt}{n^x\ln(n)}$$
$$\int \frac{n^x}{n^{2x} + 8n^x + 12}dx=\int \frac{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}}{t^{2} + 8t + 12}dt$$
$$\int \frac{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}}{t^{2} + 8t + 12}dt=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\int \frac{1}{t^{2} + 8t + 16-4}dt=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\int \frac{1}{(t+4)^2-(2)^2}dt$$

WKT.
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\log \left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|+C$$
$$\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\int \frac{1}{(t+4)^2-(2)^2}dt=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\log \left|\frac{t+4-2}{t+4+2}\right|+ C$$
$$=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\log \left|\frac{t+2}{t+6}\right| + C$$
$$=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\log \left|\frac{n^x+2}{n^x+6}\right| + C$$

EDIT:

To prove that:$\int \frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\log \left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|+C$
rewrite $x^2-a^2$ as $(x-a)(x+a)$
$$\frac{1}{(x-a)(x+a)}=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{1}{x+a}\right)$$

and integrate as usual.

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you for explaining it in such detail!! :)

Comment: Glad you found this useful :)

Comment: Also the question specifically talked about watching out for $n=1$ since $\ln(n)$ would then be $0$. How would I work with this case (if I had to separately)?

Comment: @user890948 for  $n=1$ the integrand becomes constant?the answer would be $\int \frac{1^x}{1^{2x}+8.1^x+12} dx = \frac{x}{21}$

Comment: Ohh, I see - so I would have to take the $n=1$ and $n \ne 1$ cases separately. Thanks for your help!! :)